# "Implode" / "Database Deadlock" errors on Civi Webform

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, error

Using Drupal 7.69 and CiviCRM 5.20.2, with Webform 7.x-4.21 and Webform CiviCRM Integration 7.x-4.28.

I have a Drupal webform node that uses custom fields from CiviCRM. This webform has been working well but recently a member of the public called and said it didn't let them submit their form. I looked into the Drupal error log and found 7 error messages. Did some searching but couldn't find any solutions.

All error messages located here: https://pastebin.com/A5vn0VWN

I made my own submission on the webform and it went through but I still saw the following message in the error log. Key difference between the error log for the public (failed) submission and my submission is that for both submissions the following error was logged -- for my successful submission, it was logged once, but for the failed submission, it was logged twice. So I feel like this might be important.

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in
>   CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::postProcess() (line 1494 of
>   /MYHOME/FOLDER/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php).

Anyone know how to fix this (or what the problem is in the first place)? Wasn't able to decode anything from the error log...

Comment: What version of webform and webform_civicrm are you using

Comment: @Yossi I've added version numbers to question thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error you're looking at is not the real issue.

The real issue (as showing in your pastebin log) is the deadlocks re: group contact cache.

You may need to rebuild some of your smart groups, or disable them.